# How to store only the user id not whole user inside another document in strapi JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, strapi, mongodb-atlas

From:
The document struture like this

```
{
    name:"hello",
    user:[ 
        {_id:"namejkcnskcn1",username:"username1",name:"name1",...},
        {_id:"namejkcnskcn2",username:"username2",name:"name2",...},
        {_id:"namejkcnskcn3",username:"username3",name:"name3",...}
    ]
}
```

To this one to avoid waste of storage

```
{
    name:"hello",
    user:[ "namejkcnskcn","namejkcnskcn","namejkcnskcn"  ]//only ID's
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making "user" as a array of object, you can make the "user" a simple array of id's.

This is the schema

```
users: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'   }]
```

Hope this will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```js
const a = {
    name:"hello",
    user:[ 
        {_id:"namejkcnskcn1",username:"username1",name:"name1"},
        {_id:"namejkcnskcn2",username:"username2",name:"name2"},
        {_id:"namejkcnskcn3",username:"username3",name:"name3"}
    ]
}

let b = {
  ...a,
  user: a.user.map(val => val._id)
}

console.log(b)
```